# Como alterar o Auto-increment de Id para id-Ano?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Gostaria de saber se é possível em lavável alterar o `auto-increment` de “Id” para “id-Ano”

Exemplo:

Quando temos um user com o Id:2 queria que tivesse id: 2-2021

Se for possível como poderei fazer esta alteração ?

Answer (score 0):

**Partindo do princípio que usas mysql 5.7+, e Laravel 5.3+.**

Apesar de não perceber a usabilidade disso que pedes (pois uma coluna autoincrement teoricamente há de ser única, independentemente do ano) deves ter em mente que para fazeres precisas de uma coluna autoincrement, quer automatizada em base de dados ou no código (PHP/Laravel).

Eu não aconcelho alterar a coluna `id` (esta coluna pode ter o nome que quiseres, isto é só convenção), em vez disso nas migrações do laravel deves [acrescentar uma coluna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration) como:

```
...
$table->string('uid')->storedAs('CONCAT(id, '-',  YEAR(CURDATE()))')->unique();
...
```

Neste caso caso dei o nome a esta coluna como `uid`, no entanto podes dar a que quiseres.

**Caso uses apenas MySQL 5.7+:**

Podes fazer isto logo no mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE <NOME TABELA> ADD uid INTEGER AS (CONCAT(id, '-', YEAR(CURDATE()))) STORED
```

Depois para uma busca, podes simplesmente:

```
SELECT * FROM <NOME TABELA> WHERE uid = CONCAT(<ID>, '-', YEAR(CURDATE()))
```